# Is it possible to download or read a file list or directory list from dropbox and export to a file (txt)?

Tags: file, web, dropbox, dropbox-api

I´m trying to get the list of files from a dropbox folder, I need to get the file name list and the url's from this files. Is it possible? Any idea?

Comment: I don't know anything about the dropbox api but from looking at it for a brief second I found: http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html . If you scroll to "searchFileNames" that may be of interest to you. Also take a look at the Path Class. Note these docs are in php but available in many other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Dropbox offers an API that covers all of this functionality. For example:

- to list files:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata

- to download files:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET

- to upload files:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put

- to share files via shared links:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares

There are also official SDKs available we recommend using:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core

Comment: This post is old. dropbox already have v2 to be used and v1 is deprecated.